# how can i remove page title on desktop view

Tags: pages, title

i have a problem with my woocommerce, I cant remove the page title in the product on desktop view. Anyone know what can i do ? thank you very much

store https://kingsport.ro

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write the CSS into style.css file

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .single-product .title-desc {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

`.single-product` CSS will only work on single product details. It will not create any issue on other pages.

Comment: guys thanks for helping but maybe I did it wrong but didn't work. Can you tell me exactly where to paste the code maybe I pasted it somewhere else? I added it on style.css but nothing changed. thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J8kX.jpg

Comment: If it is not working there, you can go appearance -> customize ->additional CSS box and put the CSS there

Comment: Also you will clear the cache.

Comment: I tryed that and look for tutorials but my additional css looks different, what could it be? https://ibb.co/gtwWLSw

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css to remove the title on desktop view through the media query

```
.post-type-archive-product .page-title {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: guys thanks for helping but maybe I did it wrong but didn't work. Can you tell me exactly where to paste the code maybe I pasted it somewhere else? I added it on style.css but nothing changed. thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J8kX.jpg

Comment: Please add these style in "wp-content/themes/wr-nitro/assets/woorockets/css/main.css" this file 

.title-desc > h1 {display:none !important;}

Comment: hi, thanks but still didn't work :( https://ibb.co/kMMCZYQ

Comment: HI You want to remove Title from these pages am i correct?
https://kingsport.ro/product/tricicleta-copii-4-in-1-babyking-pink-roz-multifunctionala-scaun-rotativ-suport-picioare-capotina-detasabila/

Comment: hi, yes man so as you can see when you go to all products page view it show that ugly title , but only on desktop, on mobile no problem.... So i can't figure out how to remove it to not have that ugly text space https://ibb.co/XC6t6xk